# How can I use "in spite of" rather than "although"?

Tags: conjunctions, personal-pronouns

> My health hasn't improved although I take prescribed medicine regularly.

If I rewrite this sentence by using " In spite of ", should the pronoun "I" be put or not? For example:

> In spite of I taking prescribed medicine regularly, my health hasn't improved.

Comment: Despite is the more fitting word here. Preposition meaning "without being affected by; in spite of."

Comment: How about In spite of me taking precribed medicine regularly,my health has not improved.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition phrase **in spite of** requires that a noun phrase of some kind must follow it - you can't just put a sentence there.

The correct phrasing is:

> In spite of taking prescribed medicine regularly, my health hasn't improved.

The noun phrase *taking prescribed medicine regularly* refers to the act, and the person doing it, which was previously **I**, is now provided by the second part of the sentence, *my health hasn't improved*.

Comment: I'd like to add that people sometimes say "in spite of me/my [participle]". I'm not sure how "correct" this is, but you can use this to specify the subject of the "in spite of" clause if it differs from the other clause: "Our team lost the game, in spite of me scoring 9 goals".

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi Isn't the subject of the gerund a possessive pronoun?

Comment: @V.Lydia Logically it "should" be, but I hear people use "me/you/etc." all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer, you could also say "in spite of my taking medicine regularly". The subject of the gerund is a possessive pronoun.